# Chef - How to get the output of a command to a Ruby variable

Tags: chef-infra, engineyard

Chef - How to get the output of a command to a Ruby variable

I have the below scenario where i grep for a file

```
command "ls /filder1 | grep .txt"
```

grep gives an output of the filename/filenames if they exists .,

I want to store the output to a ruby variable and use it in the template to generate a config file.

How do i do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chef is Ruby so you can use backticks `` output = `find /filder1  | grep .txt` ``

Comment: but how to do that on the node?

Comment: Chef-Solo and variants runs exclusively on the node. Chef Client does some things to figure out what to run, downloads the needed files, then basically runs chef-solo ( at least last I looked in verison 10 and 11 ).

It will have the results from the node running it as far as I know

Comment: Won't that get executed during the compilation pass through, as opposed to when Chef is running the converge process?